# How rootview tree's draw method is called in android?

Tags: android, rootview

I want to replicate the root tree in android without bitmaps i.e I want the android component to render root tree as many times I need.

For this I want to know where the draw method of RootView is called in android.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: there is no `RootView` class in the SDK

Comment: Updated the title. In android app, a view tree is build for view which is called by android framework for rendering. I want to know from where android framework call this view tree for rendering.

Comment: see `com/android/internal/policy/DecorView.java` and `com/android/internal/policy/PhoneWindow.java`